# Regular Expression for last value in comma separated list

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that returns everything after the last comma in a comma separated list.

```
// So if my list is as followed
var tag_string = "red, green, blue";

// Then my match function would return
var last_tag = tag_string.match(A_REGEX_I_CANNOT_FIGURE_OUT_YET);

// Then in last tag I should have access to blue

// I have tried the following things: 
var last_tag = tag_string.match(",\*");

// I have seen similar solutions, but I cannot figure out how to get the only the last string after the last comma.
```

Comment: Could also use `split()`: http://jsfiddle.net/VCNpQ/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var last_tag = tag_string.match("[^,]+$").trim();
```

This will first get `" blue"` then remove the trailing spaces.

Comment: This one includes the trim syntax which is pretty legit. This one worked perfectly.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt I'm glad to have helped if you decide to use this :)

Comment: Just a heads up, it looks like the trim will error if called while tag_string is null. Not an issue but just thought you would like to know in case you are implementing something similar in the future.

Answer (score 3):

```
([^,]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/IHcjcATo3S2GHtbJ)

Answer (score 2):

```
[^,]+$
```

seems to do the trick. It matches `blue`.

Answer (score -1):

```
tag_string.match(/[^,\s]+$/)

=> [ 'blue', index: 12, input: 'red, green, blue' ]
```

Thats it :)

Comment: That won't work if there are no commas in the list... For instance "red" is a comma separated list of one item.

Comment: :) But the question was for an comma seperated list. From the Result take the second argument and tada there it is. Without whitespaces. Okay its not true for all signs in the utf-8 range ^^ but it works

Comment: Yeah, but if it would only have to work on the specific input, the result can be computed faster by simply stating `"blue"` :)

Comment: maybe /[^,\s]+$/ would be better ^^

Comment: Indeed and this will work when there is comma in the input as well :P.

Comment: if you edit your post to not be specifically for comma-separated, i will `+1`.